# Is there a Subversion 1.7 GUI Client for OSX Lion?

Tags: macos, subversion

We are looking for a Subversion client for OSX Lion that support version 1.7, but we cannot find one.

Is there "an app for that"? :-)

Comment: Both Versions.app and Cornerstone.app don't support Subversion 1.7 yet, but I'd wait a little longer for them to get it implemented. I can't suggest anything else as I don't think there's anything with the same level of GUI integration at the moment.

Comment: Contacted Cornerstone and they gave me this link: http://www.zennaware.com/blog/2011/10/subversion-1_7/

Answer (score 3):

Cornerstone just updated to 1.7 on Feb. 10th http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/index.php

Answer (score 1):

You can configure svnX (free client) to use SVN 1.7 by changing "path to SVN binaries" in Preferences to your SVN 1.7 install path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you please add more information about the software you mentioned? Links are always nice! :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is [SmartSVN](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/index.html) (not free). In latest version they've [fixed](http://www.syntevo.com/smartsvn/changelog.txt) some Subversion 1.7 related bugs.

Answer (score 0):

[Versions](http://www.versionsapp.com/) is a very nice one. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899/best-subversion-client-for-mac-os) on Stackoverflow.